# How to open a page from a URL inside $mdDialog?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I have the following angular controller:

```
.controller('DialogController', function($scope, $mdDialog, $http) {
    $scope.status = '  ';
    $scope.showAdvanced = function(ev) {
        $mdDialog.show({
            controller: DialogController,
            template: '<md-dialog>' +
                '  <md-dialog-content>' +
                '    {{data}}' +
                '  </md-dialog-content>' +
                '</md-dialog>',
            parent: angular.element(document.body),
            targetEvent: ev,
            clickOutsideToClose:true
        })
        function DialogController($scope, $mdDialog) {
            $http.get('http://www.example.com/page/test/test?id=10475').success(function(data) {
                $scope.data = data;
                $scope.closeDialog = function() {
                    var mainApp = angular.element(document.body).controller();
                    $mdDialog.hide();
                }
            }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log("Error in retrieving data from server");
            });
        }
    };
});
```

I want to open a page from a url inside my Dialog. I tried to get the page but I got the complete HTML of my page. How can I open the page from the URL (`$http.get`) inside my `$mdDialog` as if it is like an iframe?

Comment: Where do you want to use that `html` ?

Comment: @RayonDabre I want to get my page from a url inside the dialog. Sorry, I have not explained well. I edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

add a data binding to your template 'dialog1.tmpl.html' like
dialog1.tmpl.html

```
...
{{serverTemplate}}
...
```

and in controller just set after getting the markup

```
$http.get('http://www.example.com/page/test/test?id=10475').success(function(data) {
    $scope.serverTemplate = data;
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much! But I want to get the page, not the HTML of the page. Sorry, I had not explained my question.

Answer (score 1):

I just did this and it worked :

```
<md-dialog-content style="height:568px;width:320px;overflow:scroll;">
<div class="md-dialog-content" id="dialog-content">
<iframe src="http://www.google.com/" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen style="position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0;width: 100%;height: 90%;" align="center"></iframe>
</div>
</md-dialog-content>
```

The style mentioned inside the iframe will ensure that you dont get double or two scroll bars inside the popup

The most important takeaway here is never close an iframe like this : `<iframe />`
Instead always close like this:

```
<iframe></iframe>
```